# Oracle Regexp_replace to add double quotes or remove all attributes per element

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I need help either adding double quotes for html element attributes that don't contain double quotes or stripping the elements attributes completely. I prefer the former to be given as an answer first, and if it can't be done, then removing the attributes from the html element will do.

I have a pattern that allows me to at least check for all = signs within a single element, but I can't get any further than that.

```
(<*=(*?)([[:alpha:]])|[[^>|"|'''']]>)
```

example source string:

```
<html><body bg= "fff" gg=ddd ss=aa></body></html>
```

I know that using regex with html is not a good idea but this is a fairly simple regex pattern that should match inside html.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed removing all the attributes from all tags using the below pattern.

```
<([^\!][a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>
```

using `<\1\2>` as the replace string.